# Generate one dimensional array of integers with array length of 10, ranging from 1 to 20

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to help my brother in his algorithm assignment, only I'm not familiar with C#, and I'm also confused with the problem.

Basically the instruction is to generate a one dimensional array of integers with length of 10, ranging from 1 to 20. Then print the maximum sum of integers where when you divide the array by two, the sum of integers on the left side is less than the sum of integers on the right side.

**Example Result:**

Generated Array of Integers: 1,5,10,3,5,20,6,8,2,14

Left Side Maximum = **24** (1+5+10+3+5=24)

Right Side Maximum = **50** (20+6+8+2+14=50)

Generating the array is easy, the confusing part is that the first half of the array must have a total sum less than the second half. Any help would be really appreaciated!

Comment: Move the split index step by step from left to right while keeping track of the sums of either side. So initially, with split index < 0, you have left = 0, right = 74. With split index @ 0 (value 1) you have left = 1, right = 73, split index=1 (value 5) => left = 6, right = 68, and so on. Continue this until left >= right and you know you've just passed the correct split point.

Comment: While I can try to research and understand this, example code will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think that good idea is to checking sums of left and right part of array during generating. If in some moment left sum is bigger than you can add to next right number difference between sums.

```
    Random random = new Random();
    int[] array = new int[10];
    int sumleft = 0;
    int sumright = 0;
    int number;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length / 2; i++)
    {
        number = random.Next(1, 21);
        array[i] = number;
        sumleft += array[i];
        number = random.Next(1, 21);
        sumright += number;
        if (sumleft >= sumright)
        { 
            number += sumleft - sumright + 1;
            sumright += sumleft - sumright + 1;
        }
        array[i + 5] = number;
    }
```

I checked results couple of times and always right part of array is bigger than left and numbers are in the indicated range.